# Finding cumulative area in ArcGIS for selected polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, area

I have 50 polygons of 5 different classes viz. A,B,C,D,E. and a field in the attribute table for area of each polygons. I want to add a field which give the cumulative area of the polygons of a particular class. e.g. if I query the attribute table for class A polygons, the cumulative area field give the cumulative area of the class A polygons. Likewise for class B polygons and so on. How can I do this in ArcGIS? The field calculator in ArcGIS gives the cumulative area of all the polygons, but not of particular class after query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate approach is to run the [Summary Statistics tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000) setting your class field to be the case field and statistics field to be the Shape Area field with Statistic Type set to SUM. This will create a non-spatial table listing sum of area by class which you could then join back to your original polygon layer using the class field.

Answer (score 2):

I would run [Dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000) GP tool and choose the class field as the Dissolve field. This will create a new polygon feature class which would have five features, each will represent "the merged" geometry of all polygons within a certain class. Create a new field and calculate the geometry (right-click column and choose Calculate Geometry). Then you can join this feature class to the source feature class by using the class field.

You will get:

```
name class area
aaa   1     567
bbb   1     567
ccc   2     453
ddd   2     453
eee   2     453
```

I hope you understand that the sum area for the class will be the same for each polygon in the feature class since they belong to the same class. It might be a bit redundant to store the data like this, but hope it will serve its purpose.